# pass image data as parameter in Ajax Call to webservice

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, call

I am trying to send image data to be processed in web service method, I made an Ajax call but I faced a problem when the image size is 2 MB, the problem is that web method didn't receive the call.

This is my client code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveImageWS.asmx/SaveToSql",
    data: "{'imageData': '" + imgData + "' ,'imageSize': " + imgSize + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    timeout: 1000000,
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError            
});
```

and this is the Web Service method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SaveToSql(string imageData, string imageSize)
{   
   // save image to database
}
```

if anyone has any info about this I will be very thankful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using firebug and seeing what that says about your call to SaveToSql?

Answer (score 0):

U just try this

```
  var Resourcelist = new Array();
  var projectlist = new Array();

Data = { imageData: JSON.stringify(projectlist), imageSize: JSON.stringify(Resourcelist) };
```

this is also works in IE